# Haskell minimum function applied to a tuple

Tags: haskell

While hunting for a bug, deep in some Haskell code, I found minimum used on a tuple. The code was expecting the smallest value to be returned. This took me a long time to debug. Can anyone explain why minimum behaves as it does with tuples? This feels like an easy mistake to make.

```
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> minimum [0,2]
0
Prelude> minimum [2,0]
0
Prelude> minimum (0,2)
2
Prelude> minimum (2,0)
0
Prelude>
```

Comment: One way to put it: the `Foldable` instance for pairs handles `(a, b)` as a `b` value with a tag, of an unrelated type `a`, attached to it. (The same goes for the `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Monad` and `Traversable` instances.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 2-tuple is an instance of the [`Foldable` typeclass with [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#line-763):

> ```
> instance Foldable ((,) a) where
>     foldMap f (_, y) = f y
>
>     foldr f z (_, y) = f y z
>     length _  = 1
>     null _ = False
> ```

It thus is an instance of `Foldable` in the sense that it is a collection of *one* element: the second one. This thus means that `minimum` on a 2-tuple will always return the second item.

Whether it was a good idea to make a 2-tuple an instance of `Foldable` has some discussion since a lot of operations like `sum`, `minimum`, `length`, all work as if it is a collection with a single element. `length` for example returns `1` for a 2-tuple.

It however makes sense that `minimum` will not work on a 2-tuple. In that case for `minimum :: (Foldable f, Ord a) => f a -> a`, and hence it works with `f ~ (,) b`, hence the signature for the 2-tuple is `Ord a => (b, a) -> a`. It thus works with 2-tuples where the two items can have different types, hence retrieving the minimum of the two is impossible, since the type constraint does not allow to compare the two items at all.